# getting individual records from a group by

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, one is a table of names with a category tag and the other is a table of scores for each name

```
ID    Name      Category
1     Dave      1
2     John      1
3     Lisa      2
4     Jim       2
```

and the score table is

```
PersonID      Score
1             50
2             100
3             75
4             50
4             75
```

I would then like a query that returned something like

```
Category    TotalScore    Names
1           150           Dave, John
2           200           Lisa, Jim
```

Is this possible to do with one query?

I can get the totals with a sum query and grouping by category but cannot see a way to get the names as I would like.

Many thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use group_concat:

```
select Category, sum(Score) as TotalScore, group_concat(Name) as Names from categories
join scores on scores.category = categories.category
group by category
```

Or even better:

```
group_concat(DISTINCT Name ORDER BY Name ASC SEPARATOR ',') as names
```

Comment: I have tried to add an order by at the end of the sql and now the name just returns "BLOB". Here  is the sql, any idea why it fails now that I have the order by included. Thanks.  SELECT group_concat(DISTINCT `tblnames`.`name`,' ',`tblnames`.`surname` SEPARATOR ' and ') AS 'nameOfPair', Sum(`tblpersonscores`.`score`) AS 'totalScore' FROM `tblnames` Inner Join `tblpersonscores` ON `tblpersonscores`.`personID` = `tblnames`.`id` GROUP BY `tblnames`.`category` ORDER BY 'totalScore' ASC

Comment: It's not so beautiful to see, but if you try: "select * from (SELECT group_concat(DISTINCT tblnames.name,' ',tblnames.surname SEPARATOR ' and ') AS 'nameOfPair', Sum(tblpersonscores.score) AS 'totalScore' FROM tblnames Inner Join tblpersonscores ON tblpersonscores.personID = tblnames.id GROUP BY tblnames.category) as a order by TotalScore ASC" What do you get?

Comment: This does work, but I'm not entirely sure why!! Could you explain it a little please?

Comment: I am not sure too, but I guess it orders the rows before grouping them. In this case the group_concat returns BLOB. But I repeat, I am not sure about this.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, and thanks for sorting the problem, much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Just add `group_concat(Name) as names` into your sum query.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution working for Postgres (which doesn't have a group_concat() function):

```
select category, sum(score) as TotalScore, array(select id from perso where category=P.category order by id) as Names from perso P JOIN scores S ON S."PersonID" = P.id GROUP BY category;
```

(I know this was a MySQL question, but nonetheless someone might google it up but needs an answer for Postgres :) )